# how can I use external URI with the nginx's auth_request module

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use `nginx`'s `ngx_http_auth_request_module` in such way:

```
server {

    location / {
        auth_request http://external.url;
        proxy_pass http://protected.resource;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, the error is:

```
2017/02/21 02:45:36 [error] 17917#0: *17 open() "/usr/local/htmlhttp://external.url" failed (2: No such file or directory), ...
```

Or in this way with `named location`:

```
server {

    location / {
        auth_request @auth;
        proxy_pass http://protected.resource;
    }

    location @auth {
        proxy_pass http://external.url;
    }
}
```

In this case the error is almost the same:

```
2017/02/22 03:13:25 [error] 25476#0: *34 open() "/usr/local/html@auth" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "@auth", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

I know there is a way like this:

```
server {

    location / {
        auth_request /_auth_check;
        proxy_pass http://protected.resource;
    }

    location /_auth_check {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://external.url;
    }
}
```

But in this case the `http://protected.resource` can not use the `/_auth_check` path.

Is there a way to use an external `URI` as a parameter for the `auth_request` directive without overlapping the `http://protected.resource` routing?

If not, why?
It looks a little bit strange to look for the `auth_request`'s URI through static files (`/usr/local/html`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a little known fact that you don't have to start location with `/` or `@`.

So this would work:

```
location / {
    auth_request .auth;
    proxy_pass http://protected.resource;
}

location .auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://external.url/auth;
    # you must use path part here ^
    # otherwise it would be invalid request to external.url
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not find this in documentation, is it there?

Comment: It's not there, but there is no requirement for prefix to start with `/` either.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyTen, I am trying to implement something the same but my http://external.url/auth is getting called multiple times, Did you face any such issue?